# SHA256 is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, aes, sha256, cryptojs

I was experimenting with CryptoJS library and came across with the problem that my imported hash function isn't visible inside a class. Here's my code:

```
CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
SHA256 = require('crypto-js/sha256');

class trCrypt {
  constructor(input,key) {
this.input = input;
this.key = SHA512(key).toString();
  }
  encrypt(){
    this.step1 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(this.input,this.key);
    return this.step1.toString()
  }
  decrypt(){
    const bytes =  CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(this.step1);
    this.dec1 = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    return this.dec1
  }
}
a = new trCrypt('hello','world');
console.log(a.encrypt());
console.log(a.decrypt());
```

[SOLVED] Thanks for answer!

Comment: SHA256 is defined, but not SHA512

Comment: You are importing `SHA256` but using `SHA512`. Also, you shouldn't be declaring variables globally. (Using `var` or `const` in your case is preferred)

Comment: The real question here is why do you think SHA256 module can handle SHA512 encryption? Remember, do one thing, but do it well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you've imported the CryptoJs module and the SHA256 function, but you've not imported the SHA512 function.

Try adding:

```
SHA512 = require('crypto-js/sha512');
```

On top of the script